# Replacement of numbers

Tags: assignment-operator

I am given three variables having finite values ( all are integers) m,n, r.
Now I need to do   m<-r    and    n<-r   ( assign m and n the value of r ) and I have read in "The Art of Computer Programming vol. 1 " that the operations can be combined as
m<-n<-r

But will the above statement not mean "assign m the value of n and then n the value of r".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assignment associates from right to left. So there are implicit parentheses: `m <- (n <- r)`

Answer (score 0):

The order of assignment is from right to left. Thus, `m<-n<-r` will be interpreted as: `n<-r` and then `m<-n`.

Since `n` equals `r` after the first assignment, `m<-n` and `m<-r` are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment `=` operator is like assigning the right side value to left side. For eg

```
int a = 1 + 2;
```

Here first `1+2` is evaluated and assigned to `a` because it follows right to left associativity.

Now if you have something like this

```
int a=b=2;
```

It again follows right to left associativity. From right first `b=2` is evaluated  and assign `2` to b then `b` is assigned to `a`. It works like this `a=(b=2)`

Know in your question you have `m<-n<-r` . This will work like this `m<-(n<-r)`
You can see reference [Operator Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)

Comment: A small doubt ............. I learnt that operator associativity depends on the language that we use,....... So is there a chance for my question to be valid..

Comment: @user27838 Yes, every language has it's own operator associativity . But, you have to move with the associativity defined by the language you use. The book you are reading and the language (Assembly) used follows right to left associativity for assignment . Actually most programming languages follow right to left for assignment.